# detect events on powerpoint shapes from C#

Tags: .net, user-controls, powerpoint

is it possible to detect the events which happen on a powerpoint shape like, let say, an arrow???

Until now, I've found the only possibilities are selecteditemchanged, beforerightclick and beforedoubleclick, but can't find a way to detect others like mouseover, resizeend, or positionchanged.

I was able to detect the click event on a Forms.CommandButton.1 ole object, but it works only on ppt presentation mode, not in ppt design mode.

My main goal is to embed a winform -or a wincontrol- into a ppt slide (not only show it over the slide, but embed it into the slide, so it can be viewed in the slide index and the user can play with it like any other shape. In example, male it bold, uppercase, change back color, etc), but I can't find documentation, and the one I found is not working as expected:

[This one is about smartart, but seems to not have events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg583880(v=office.14).aspx)
[This one is about using Net control as OleObject, but in my case it is raising an "Error when calling COM" error](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/11/24/using-managed-controls-as-activex-controls.aspx)

So, if it's not possible to embed Net controls within a ppt slide, is at least possible to detect key and mouse events on shapes???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution in the mean time?

Comment: Also it sounds like there is a way how to do it in something else than .net. Which one would that be?

Comment: Hi @Cilvic we stoped trying that way. The nearest we got there was by using windows hooks to detect mouse clicks on the screen, then translating that into office coordinates. But we had a lot of trouble with office versions and certain kinds of shapes. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497024/how-to-detect-mouse-clicks

Answer (score 0):

this one might help you:

[Detect Shape's events](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSExcelNewEventForShapes-0e26b1f2#content)

Answer (score 0):

This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947765/add-onclick-action-to-shape-objects-in-ms-powerpoint) may help

In other words, you can add events in Addin and filter what you want in `if` statement.