# UI Automation and Ribbon control

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation

I do automation for WPF application using UIAutomation API. Everything went fine until I hit the Ribbon control. I have no trouble to see information about Ribbon and its children through the Inspect.exe, but inside the code I cannot obtain the information about those elements.

It other words,  in this code  aeElement is always null:

```
aeElement = aeForm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
                  new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "XXX"));
```

I tried `TreeScope.Descendants` and `TreeScope.Elements`.
I tried `AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty` and `AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty`.
I tried `TreeWalker` – nothing worked.

Wondering if there is a solution for that issue?
Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT: There is no answer at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/home?forum=windowsaccessibilityandautomation either.

Comment: Whose ribbon control?

Comment: it's Microsoft ribbon

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881705/ui-automation-events-not-getting-caught-from-powerpoint-2007

Answer (score 1):

your worst case scenario is the root, correct?
then try the following solution:

a. search from the root and then go deeper into the window, context, and so goes on

b. if a didn't work, then it must be your spelling. the name is case sensitive.

c. why aren't you using AutomationID? it was created for that use!

Comment: no, root is not a problem at all; 
no spelling errors for sure; 
and as i mentioned in my question i tried AutomationId property as well - not working either

Comment: so when you search from root you don't have the problem?
if so, search deeper. it might be in a parallel scope to the window it self